# setting a javascript object property to a variable

Tags: javascript

How can I set a property of my object to a variable? The variable is equal to a form textfield value. Both `obj.property` and `obj[property]` give me a `undefined error` when I display the `mycar` object.

```
function auto(manufacturer,model,engine_size,year,color,price) 
{
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.model = model;
    this.engine_size = engine_size;
    this.year = year;
    this.color = color;
    this.price = price;
}

var mycar = new auto();

var a = document.form.num1.value;
mycar.manufacturer = a;
mycar[manufacturer] = a;
```

sorry. here is all of my code http://jsfiddle.net/vzqjv/

im trying to set my object property to a variable, a, which is equal to a form textfield value after some validation to see if it checks out.

Comment: Is this the entire code?

Comment: are you sure that "a" is not undefined?

Comment: @KhanhTo: But that won't give an error (on the mycar lines), will it?

Comment: because if "a" is undefined, when he assigned an undefined value to mycar.manufacturer, the mycar.manufacturer will be undefined.

Comment: @KhanhTo - And that is completely legal.  That will not cause an `undefined` error, just an `undefined` assignment.

Comment: @Steve: yes, i just wonder if he assigned an undefined value to mycar.manufacturer which will be undefined after the assignment.

Comment: sorry. here is all of my code http://jsfiddle.net/vzqjv/

Comment: @user1760790 - Only the second assignment is causing the `undefined` error, for exactly the reason I state in my answer below. Either you need to put quotes around `manufacturer` on that line or define what string value you want to assign the variable `manufacturer`

Comment: well, when you assign mycar.manufacturer = a; the document.form.num1.value does not have a value yet

Comment: See updated code (which doesn't throw an error): http://jsfiddle.net/vzqjv/1/

Comment: @KhanhTo - That might be a problem for what the OP wants this code to do, but is NOT the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1):

`mycar.manufacturer = a` assigns `a` to a property of `mycar` named `manufacturer`.

`mycar[manufacturer] = a` assigns `a` to a property of `mycar` with the same name as the value of a variable `manufacturer`. You probably meant `mycar["manufacturer"] = a`.

Answer (score 1):

The second notation

```
mycar[manufacturer] = a;
```

should be

```
mycar["manufacturer"] = a;
```

The first notation should work.  Are you modifying mycar in a way that we don't see?

My guess is that the undefined error is actually on this line:

```
var a = document.form.num1.value;
```

is that being defined correctly?

Comment: `document.form.num1.value;` seems to be returning correctly according to dev tools. It's probably just the `mycar[manufacturer]`!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared your variable `manufacturer`, so it is undefined when you do `mycar[manufacturer] = a;`.  You need to either define it

```
var a = document.form.num1.value,
    manufacturer = "manufacturer";
mycar.manufacturer = a;
mycar[manufacturer] = a;
```

or use quotes:

```
var a = document.form.num1.value;
mycar.manufacturer = a;
mycar["manufacturer"] = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give the definition of the auto. I guess you don't have the manufacturer property in it. Another way is just do

```
var mycar = {};
var a = document.form.num1.value;
mycar.manufacturer = a;
```